# RF channel noise interference calculation

Tags: rf, noise, signal-to-noise, power-spectral-density

I am trying to calculate how far a co-channel or noise source has to be from the primary channel, in this case a WiFi channel, for it not to interfere with the link performance.

[image]

This question takes basis of a WiFi channel(2.4GHz), but it could be any RF link. The links are LoS for easier calculations.(no reflections from walls, etc.)

Assume we have a WiFi router with EIRP = +20dBm / 100mW, and this channel is 40 MHz wide, therefore the power spectral density is:

$$PSD_{40MHz} = 100 mW/40MHz = 2.5mW/MHz = +4dBm/MHz$$

Assume our noise source has the same PSD:
$$PSD_{noise} = +4dBm/MHz$$

Also, for this case with a WiFi link, assume we need a minimum of 25dB SNR for the channel.

The user is located 20m from the router. This mean the FSPL is:
$$FSPL_{20m} = 66dB$$

This means that for the noise source not have influence on the SNR of the RF channel, it needs to have a path loss equal to:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
   FSPL_{NoiseToUser} &= (PSD_{noise} - PSD_{40MHz}) + SNR + FSPL_{20m} \\\\
    &= (+4dBm/MHz - +4dBm/MHz) + 25dB + 66dB = \textbf{91dB/MHz}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Solving for distance, this means that with a required path loss of 91dB, the noise source has to be \$\textbf{350m}\$ away for it not to influence the SNR!

This doesnt seem right to me, but i can't figure out what im doing wrong. Is there a problem with my method of calculating this?

Comment: WiFi co-channel interference is not simple additive noise - have you taken into account the carrier-sense behaviors of the protocol?

Comment: @nanofarad, i have not no. Im not sure how to do that. What if we assume the noise source is just white noise?

Comment: The point of carrier sense is that WiFi devices are aware of other WiFi transmissions on the same channel (by detecting preambles and other mechanisms), so they don't interfere additively. A white noise source with that same PSD is a very different problem altogether, and sounds more like the situation where carrier sense breaks down due to the [hidden node problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_node_problem), e.g. when the user is on the top of a hill and has line of sight to both transmitters, but the transmitters cannot detect each other and end up not backing off.